# Using python generators in scikit-learn

Tags: python, generator, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was wondering whether and how it is possible to use a python generator as data input to scikit-learn classifier's .fit() functions? Due to huge amounts of data, this seems to make sense to me.

In particular I am about to implement a random forest approach.

Regards
K

Comment: Why don't you try it an see for yourself? This doesn't seem like the kind of thing you can't figure out on your own.

Comment: @InbarRose that seems to not to be so straightforward to me. A classic random forest is not an online classifier, so easy answer is "you can't". There are some approaches to deal with this, but tricky ones and I doubt they are implemented in sklearn.

Comment: what is unclear about this question?

Comment: I find the question clear myself and both larsmans and alko's answers are correct. The [on hold] tag should be removed in my opinion.

Comment: @larsmans and alko thanx for the answers. exactly what i wanted to know. 

about the [hold on] of course i'll clarify the question if wished. i could need a suggestion about what is unclear though.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. I faced same problems. At least i used  numpy slide tricks to has as less copies as possible to create X and y, but being able to use generator and do slicing inside would be much better imho

Comment: Answers like try it on your own doesn't help anybody, please don't do that

Comment: Check about incremental learning (https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887202/is-there-an-option-like-generator-in-keras-with-scikit-to-process-large-records

Answer (score 12):

The answer is "no". To do out of core learning with random forests, you should

1. Split your data into reasonably-sized batches (restricted by the amount of RAM you have; bigger is better);
2. train separate random forests;
3. append all the underlying trees together in the `estimators_` member of one of the trees (untested):

   ```
   for i in xrange(1, len(forests)):
       forests[0].estimators_.extend(forests[i].estimators_)`
   ```

(Yes, this is hacky, but no solution to this problem has been found yet. Note that with very large datasets, it might pay to just sample a number training examples that fits in the RAM of a big machine instead of training on all of it. Another option is to switch to linear models with SGD, those implement a `partial_fit` method, but obviously they're limited in the kind of functions they can learn.)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "No, you can't". Classical Random Forest classifier is not an incremental or online classifier, so you can't discard training data while learning, and have to provide all the dataset at once.

Due to popularity of RF in machine learning (not least because of the good prediction results for some interesting cases), there are some attempts to implement online variation of Random Forest, but to my knowledge those are not yet implemented in any python ML package.

See [Amir Saffari's page](http://www.ymer.org/amir/software/online-random-forests/) for such an approach (not Python).