# Is there an option like generator in keras with scikit to process large records of data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, training-data

I have a training dataset of shape(90000,50) and I trying to fit this in model(Gaussian process regression). This errors out with memory error. I do understand the computation, but is there way to pass data in batches using scikit? I am using the scikit implementation of the GPR algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Keras has generator because, you can create checkpoints and resume from where you left off in Neural Networks. However, not all of trainable algorithms has this property. Take a look at [incremental learning](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) from Scikit-API docs.

Comment: yes, however not all algorithms work based on the incremental learning. I am using a gaussian regression process and it doesnt support partial_fit. So looking for an alternative to pass data (manually/ scikit methods ) in batches.

Comment: That was what I am saying. You cannot do this if you are working with a class that does not implement `partial_fit`. You can derive from `GaussianProcessRegressor` to implement a `partial_fit` if you have an iterative way of fitting gaussian processes. If you do not, try looking into local Gaussian Process learners which combine into a global Gaussian Process model. Search for "Infinite Mixtures of Gaussian Process Experts" article from Rasmussen and Ghahramani.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

The Gaussian process implementation(Regression/classification) from scikit is'nt capable of handling big dataset. It can run only upto 15000 rows of data. So I decided to use a different algorithm instead as this seems to be a problem with algorithm.