# How to solve Numpy array causing ArrayMemoryError and MemoryError in 256 GB RAM system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, numpy, memory

I am using Windows 10. My system configuration is RAM = 256 GB and Hard Drive = 2 TB. I am using PyCharm community edition for coding. And I am using `python` version shown below:

```
Python 3.9.7 [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

My data is of size 1.2 million rows with some 7000 columns. When I tried to fit the processed data into a `Scikit-learn` Random Forrest model, I get the following error:

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 431, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 285, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 209, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 674, in _fit_and_score
    X_test, y_test = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, test, train)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py", line 286, in _safe_split
    X_subset = _safe_indexing(X, indices)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 377, in _safe_indexing
    return _array_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 201, in _array_indexing
    return array[key] if axis == 0 else array[:, key]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\memmap.py", line 331, in __getitem__
    res = super(memmap, self).__getitem__(index)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 721. MiB for an array with shape (120000, 7000) and data type uint8
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 45, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 891, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 1766, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 838, in evaluate_candidates
    out = parallel(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 445, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 721. MiB for an array with shape (120000, 7000) and data type uint8
```

I tried some of the solutions here:

1. Increasing the console memory of PyCharm. [Increase output buffer when running or debugging in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355460/increase-output-buffer-when-running-or-debugging-in-pycharm)
2. Increasing the size of paging file size [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

But these are not working. How can I solve this issue when I have plenty of memory in RAM and hard drive? I tried it with PyCharm, Jupyter, and google colab. I also tried simply running the script with commandline. But it displays the same error.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952691/16744221 could help you. I haven't tested it, but it seems like you will not be able to use a generator to train your random forest at once.

Comment: That array doesn't look that big.  I suspect there are many more arrays that chew up memory.

Comment: @hpaulj I am using all the 64 cores in `n_jobs=-1` parameter. May be that is why?

Comment: I haven't worked with large multicore computers, so can't help.

Comment: Maybe upgrading to Linux is an option? Or running outside an IDE, directly with Python.

Comment: @MarkSetchell unfortunately updating to linux is not an option. I have to work with windows. I tried with `python` command line. But resulted in the same error.